# Silently install Office Online XML Add-ins

Tags: xml, office365

Is there any way to silently install add-ins for Office Online?

[This](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish) article from Microsoft explains how to deploy add-ins for other users to find, but each method listed requires some user interaction. Is there any way to skip the user interaction and install the add-in automatically?

Comment: I'd be surprised if they'd support some sneaky injection. IMHO this is a security-critical subject. And there's better no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Outlook, via Powershell: [New-App](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218722(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: Does this require that the user have a version of Office installed on their local computer?

Answer (score 0):

not sure you checked out [this](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-preview-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) link on the article you referenced.
You can try the preview today, and basically this feature allows an IT Admin via O365 administration ui (or soon with powershell commands) to deploy add-ins to users or groups within the organization. I recommend you yo try it! The team is actively working to enable support for Online clients, so that will be available quite soon.

Hopefully that will answer your question.

thanks!
Juan.